# Display error message in Login Blade file

Tags: laravel-8

I have below code in my login controller.

```
return redirect('/login')->withErrors('Login is not successful.');
```

I am displaying all error messages using below code in `login.blade.php` file.

```
@if ($errors->any())
     @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
           <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                 {{ $error }}
           </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

If I use above code all the errors are displaying. I would like to display only error of  `return redirect('/login')->withErrors('Login is not successful.');` this code.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can flush errors from session right before you redirect, can you try this:

```
\Session::flush('errors');
return redirect('/login')->withErrors('Login is not successful.');
```